# how to find the generator of elliptic curve using matlab

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

my question is that 
my Matlab program for elliptic curve generated all points which satisfy the elliptic curve equation
now how to find the generator which generates all the points
example:

```
 ecs(1,0,17)
ans =
     (0     0)
     (0     0)
     (1     6)
     (1    11)
    ( 3     8)
    ( 3     9)
     (4     0)
     (6     1)
     (6    16)
    (11     4)
    (11    13)
    (13     0)
    (14     2)
    (14   15)
    (16     7)
    (16    10)
```

Comment: Easiest way is to try each point and see which works

Comment: Computing (generators of) the mordell-weil group of an elliptic curve is a hard problem in general. I doubt there is an existing matlab implementation, and implementing one would be a long task, instead I would suggest you use an existing non-matlab program such as https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/mwrank/ or SageMath https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_rational_field.html#sage.schemes.elliptic_curves.ell_rational_field.EllipticCurve_rational_field.gens